# Webscraping of links from a web page in R

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to get also links to the properties - but for some reason, I am not getting all the links from each page, this code works but only for the **first page**. What I am missing regarding the `link` extraction?

```
# To get $rooms, $m2, $price, $link
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

flat_I = data.frame()

for (i in 7:100) {
  link <- paste0("https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/immobilie-kaufen/seite-", i)
  page <- read_html(link)
  
  #parse out the parent nodes
  results <- page %>% html_elements(".DHILY")
  
  #retrieve the rooms, m2 and price from each parent
  rooms <- results %>% html_element(".ufaLY:nth-child(1)") %>%
    html_text()
  
  m2 <- results %>% html_element(".ufaLY:nth-child(2)") %>%
    html_text()
  
  price <- results %>% html_element(".tSnnN") %>%
    html_text()
  
  link <- page %>% 
    html_nodes("a._aOSG") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>% 
    paste0("https://www.immobilienscout24.at", ., sep="")
  
  flat_I = rbind(flat_I, data.frame(rooms, m2, price, link, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  print(paste("Page:", i))
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are located in two classes `s5PQF` and `YXjuW` we can extract links fro them individually or get all the links from page and filter them to retain only desired links.

Further you have defined `link` twice in your loop avoid such repetitions.

```
library(stringr)

page %>% html_nodes('a') %>% 
    html_attr('href') %>% unique() %>% 
    str_subset('expose')
```

Comment: Thank you :) how did you know that there are two classes? Through inspect? I see only this class="_aOSG".

Comment: Yeah, through inspect. Class `s5PQF ` is child of `_aOSG`. On page eight we could get only nine links because others were associated with class `YXjuW`